# SQL Order by a float column not working

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the following rows in my db:

```
ID       Weight
-----------------------------
897      1.46357497509608E-11
689      6.67145488899268E-12
896      6.63573718293682E-12
615      5.14817058560092E-12
822      5.14806820534293E-12
```

When I execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY weight DESC
```

the data is being returned in the same order.

P.S. the same thing is happening from a Linq query in an ASP.NET C# application

Comment: And why is that not the right order?, the first value is `1.45*10^-11`, wich is greater than `6.67*10^-12`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That order is correct.

Descending order means that the largest values come first. Your numbers are being displayed in [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). 1.46E-11 means 1.46 × 10<sup>-11</sup> which is equal to 0.0000000000146.

Seeing the numbers in ordinary decimal form may help to understand why the order is correct:

```
ID   Weight
897  0.00000000001463574975096080
689  0.00000000000667145488899268
896  0.00000000000663573718293682
615  0.00000000000514817058560092
822  0.00000000000514806820534293
```